# Why GCC won't give me stackerror on long arguments?

Tags: c, gcc, stack-overflow

My point is to show someone that every argument you sent to a C function, are pushed on the stack. It also happens in Ruby, Python, Lua, JavaScript, etc.

So I have written a Ruby code that generates a C code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

str = Array.new(10, &:itself)

a = <<~EOF
    #include <stdio.h>

    void x(#{str.map { |x| "int n#{x}" }.join(?,)}) {
        printf("%d\\n", n#{str.length - 1}) ;
    }

    int main() { x(#{str.join(?,)}) ; }
EOF

IO.write('p.c', a)
```

After running this code with the Ruby interpreter, I get a file called p.c, which has this content:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void x(int n0,int n1,int n2,int n3,int n4,int n5,int n6,int n7,int n8,int n9) {
    printf("%d\n", n9) ;
}

int main() { x(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) ; }
```

Which is good, and does compile and execute just fine.

But if I give the ruby program an array size of 100,000, it should generate a C file that takes n0 to n999999 arguments. That means 100,000 arguments.

A quick google search shows me that C's arguments are stored on the stack.

Passing these arguments should give me a stackerror, but it doesn't. GCC compiles it just fine, I also get output of 99999.

But with Clang, I get:

```
p.c:4:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n99999'
        printf("%d\n", n99999) ;
                       ^
p.c:8:195690: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 34464, have 100000
p.c:3:6: note: 'x' declared here
2 errors generated.
```

How does GCC deal with that many arguments? In most cases, I get stackerror on other programming languages when the stacksize in 10900.

Comment: *A quick google search shows me that C's arguments are stored on the stack.*  [Google is wrong - no "stack" mentioned here...](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: Yes, "Arguments passed to a C function are pushed onto the stack, right to left, before the function is called. The first thing the called function does is push the EBP register, and then copy ESP into it. This creates a new data structure normally called the C stack frame." - https://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html

Comment: @S.Goswami, although that article may be correct about *some* (few these days) C implementations, it is not true of all C implementations in general.  Most pass some arguments in CPU registers, which is faster, using stack only where necessary.  The C language specifications have nothing to say about it either way.

Comment: @S.Goswami I linked to a copy of **the C standard**.  And what if my CPU doesn't even have an EBP register?

Comment: I am uncertain about the other languages you mentioned, but inasmuch as they are all high-level languages typically implemented in C themselves, I am inclined to think that in one sense they use *neither* the hardware stack nor CPU registers, and in another they use whatever the C implementation with which they were built uses.  There may also be other senses to consider.

Comment: Moreover, even to the extent that arguments *are* passed on the stack, it's unclear why you assume that calling a function with 100000 arguments would necessarily overflow the stack.  Programs typically have more available stack space than that would require, and most C implementations provide ways to grant more.  And if you *did* exceed the available stack, it's unlear why you think you can predict the (undefined) result.

Comment: Since you only use the last parameter of `x`, `gcc` may optimize your code into something that doesn't pass 100000 parameters in a function call

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prove this to your friend is to write an infinite recursive function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recurse(int x) {
  static int iterations=0;

  printf("Iteration: %d\n", ++iterations);
  recurse(x);
}

int main() {
  recurse(1);
}
```

This will always overflow the stack assuming there *is* a stack (not all architectures use stacks). It will tell you how many stack frames you get to before the stack overflow happens; this will give you an idea of the depth of the stack.

As for why `gcc` compiles, `gcc` does not know the target stack size so it cannot check for a stack overflow. It's theoretically possible to have a stack large enough to accommodate 100,000 arguments. That's less than half a megabyte. Not sure why `clang` behaves differently; it would depend on seeing the generated C code.

If you can share what computer system/architecture you are using, it would be helpful. You cited information that applies to 64-bit Intel systems (e.g. PC/Windows).

Comment: Yes, that might overflow the stack, but that would not establish the OP's thesis that "every argument you sent to a C function, are pushed on the stack." Indeed, even if it does overflow the stack, that is unlikely to arise from passing *any* arguments there. However, since it could be subject to tail-call optimization, that particular function might not overflow the stack after all.

Comment: Yes that's true, a factorial or fib sequence can also overflow the stack, but it's not literally sending the thousands of arguments. I have seen Ruby, Python, JS stackoverflow if you do that, also, you can't do `1+2+3+4...100000` in the interpreted languages as well. C is compiled, and clang throws error in compile time, but GCC specificaly handles that well, so that might throw off the idea that this is stored on stack, because the size of stack on my system doesn't permit > 10900 recursions...